# If symmetric $n \times n $ matrix $S^3=I_n$, does $S=I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Does $S^3=I_n$ imply $S=I_n$?

I started by looking at $S^2=I_n$ and found that this does not imply $S=I_n$, because of the counterexample
\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix} 
-\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) \\
\cos(\alpha) & \sin(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix} \end{align}
For $S^3$ however, I do not really know how to approach the problem.

Comment: It's not, rotation matrix is not symmetrical.

Comment: @RobArthan The example is not rotation, but a reflection (not determinant is -1, not +1).

Comment: the point is that $S$ is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues and $x\mapsto x^k$ for odd $k$ is injective on reals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $S$ symmetric, it's diagonalizable, since it's real - i.e $S$ is similar to a matrix with its eigenvalues on the diagonal. Consider what value these can be, if $S^3=I_n$.

Comment: The Eigenvalues have to be 1 because $\sqrt[3]{1}=1$. So $S$ is similar to $I_n$ and therefore must be $I_n$.

Answer (score 3):

By the given conditions,
\begin{aligned}
\langle (S^2+S+I)x,x\rangle
&=\langle (S^2+S^4+I)x,x\rangle\\
&=\langle Sx,Sx\rangle+\langle S^2x,S^2x\rangle+\langle x,x\rangle>0
\end{aligned}
for every nonzero vector $x$. Hence $S^2+S+I$ is nonsingular. Yet, $S^2+S+I$ divides $S^3-I$. Therefore...

Answer (score 1):

By the spectral theorem, $S$ is diagonalisable with real numbers as eigenvalues. From $S^3=I$ every eigenvalue$~\lambda$ of $S$ satisfies $\lambda^3=1$. Conclude.